# Which is more efficient: Multiple Mysql tables Per User or a Combined Table per category

Tags: mysql, database

I've been thinking a lot about Database Management and I am trying to figure out the best possible Way to Organize (Users, Products, orders, Customers, Etc).

Every User will have their own Products that the user will add into the database.

For Database Management all The users will be stored on the same table. Now my question is should all the Products be stored on the same table with a user ID assigning the products to the correct user or should the Products be stored on an individual table That is created when a user is created?

- Note: Each user can Have more than 100k products.

And also how would your answer effect product synchronization?

I'm thinking about a MySQL to SQLite and vice versa for offline use.

Comment: Do the products for different users have the same field structure?  If  so I would say use the same table with the user ID.

Comment: I'd say having dynamic tables by <entity row> is pretty complex to maintain. Usually databases can manage that kind of data with partitioning, for example. So, let the database do the job. As a more empirical answer, I'd say to just test it. Don't over-optimize before the problem is there, and in case there are performance problems, test different things. All of this heavily depends on the kind of queries you want to do

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Yes every user will have the same structure.

Comment: If your users do not need some shared data - you can probably use a completely separate SQLite database for each user. Unless you need something special like Sphinx or JSON functions or something MySQL-specific which is not available in SQLite.